# How to do a random for boucle in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to randomize a for boucle in Python?

Something like this :

```
for i in random(range(0,5)): #This is an example and not working at all

    print(i)
```

-> and the resultat should be for example :

4

2

3

1

0

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
import random
items = [x for x in range(0,5)] # create a list with items
random.shuffle(items) # shuffle it (in-place)
for i in items: # iterate over
    print(i) # print
```

for `random` see corresponding [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but my list should be like this :

list_generator = list(range(1,prime_number)) with prime number equal to 2187250724783011924372502227117621365353169430893212436425770606409952999199375923223513177023053917

If I try your code I got this error : Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t

Comment: It is completely different question, because 18446744073709551615 (2^64) is the largest number one can store in a single variable (for x64 arch). Moreover, I doubt it is possible to create list of such length because of memory limits. What is your task exactly?